# ag grid clipboard for cut action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clipboard, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to implement copy, cut, paste actions in ag grid.
Ag grid enterprise features contain all what I need except for cut action.
I think it can be implemented by adding keydown event handler to the component. The process would be consisted of just copying and erasing the cells data. But the problem is I couldn't find the which row and column I copied, the position of the cell. any idea?

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: "Athlete",
          field: "athlete",
          width: 150,
          suppressSizeToFit: true
        },
        {
          headerName: "Age",
          field: "age",
          width: 90,
          minWidth: 50,
          maxWidth: 100
        },
        ...
      ],
      defaultColDef: { editable: true },
      rowSelection: "multiple",
      clipboardDeliminator: ",",
      rowData: []
    };
}
onKeyDown(evt) {
    if (evt.key == "x" && (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey)) {
        this.gridApi.copySelectedRangeToClipboard();
        // here should add some code        
    }    
}
render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
        <div className="grid-wrapper">
          <div
            id="myGrid"
            style={{
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              height: "100%",
              width: "100%"
            }}
            className="ag-theme-balham"
            onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown.bind(this)}
          >
            <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
            enableRangeSelection={true}
            rowSelection={this.state.rowSelection}
            clipboardDeliminator={this.state.clipboardDeliminator}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
            rowData={this.state.rowData}
          />

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. there is a method for getting range selected

```
this.gridApi.getCellRanges()
```

it will return columns selected and startRow, endRow values, all I need!

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection/